# if there are one cpu core and two threads with non-blocking and non-exit, how long cpu time each thread could occupy each time?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, cpu-usage

More details of my question:

> the system platform is linux(mac), the thread task is non-blocking and looping. assuming there is only one cpu core, how long cpu time does a thread could occupy each time when there are two threads. how does cpu time change allocated to each thread when the thread number increment.

```
|------------------ one cpu time of one thread ---------------------|
|-context switch time -|----------- user code running time----------|
|------------A---------|--------------------B-----------------------|
```

> Experience shows that the performance decreasing gradually when thread number becomes too bigger. I think the performance maybe is influenced by the value of A/B(A stands for the time of context switch, B stands for the time of user code running in one cpu time slice of a thread). So if wen know how the cpu time slice changes when thread number increment, could we know the performance of our system.

I want to truly understand the cpu time allocation, could someone recommend some good readings or books about this.

Comment: `How long cpu time each thread could occupy each time?` - It depends on scheduler *policy*. Scheduling is a **broad** topic.

Comment: is linux scheduler policy different on most hardware platform like x86, arm? or it depends on the hardware performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fact 1: CPU time is not allocated, kernel periodic kick the busy-looping process which refuses to release CPU**

There is a hardware which generate interrupt at constant interval, the interrupt is called timer interrupt or `tick`. Only when tick arrives, kernel have chance to check if current running process is taking too muck cpu resource. If no interrupt triggers, the process will take control of cpu FOREVER, there won't be any chance that any other code can be run.

**Fact 2: Well designed program always release CPU when nothing to do.**

There are several functions or syscalls which can release CPU resource. eg. `select`, `epoll_wait`, blocking read/write, `wait_pid` and my least favorite `sleep` (I coded millions of lines, `sleep` is never used except in test cases).

Calling these function will release CPU resource, then kernel can schedule CPU to other processes.

**Fact 3: When all process has nothing to do and released CPU, kernel will put CPU in low power mode, which consume low power and generate less heat.**

In X86 arch, kernel will use `halt` instruction to put CPU into low power mode, which will actually hand the CPU, if no interrupt arrives, CPU will hang forever. (In tickless mode, tick will be disabled if no process active and CPU will hang forever if no network, hard disk, keyboard/mouse input or whatever interrupt arrives, which saves battery)

**Fact 4: A single busy-looping process will raise a single CPU core usage to 100%**

**Fact 5: Simple busy-looping process doesn't cause CPU generate a lot heat**

A simple looping with no I/O, few memory access (very low cache miss), very little branch, isn't bad. You can try one `for (;;) {}` loop per core, finding that your CPU fans are still resting. Because it only uses very few gates in the chip.

Games usually run at 60fps and a frame is 1s/60 = 16ms. Typical CPU period is 10-50ms, If the game releases CPU, it isn't guaranteed it will regain CPU in the next 16ms. So games usually run a simple loop which check high-precision clock constantly to achieve frame-rate more accurately. That's why games always take 100% CPU, no matter how powerful your box is.

**Fact 6: In modern system, several busy-looping process won't hang, freeze, slow your system**

The scheduler will increase the priority of well designed processes which active release CPU resource and decrease the priority of busy-looping process. In modern system, it will take less than 1% cpu resource to response your keyboard/mouse input or ssh/bash, so the process which handle user input can easily beats busy-looping processes and take control of CPU resource.

Hope these will help you understand how scheduler works

Comment: Thanks~, it's very clear to understand how kernel scheduler works. and "Typical CPU period is 10-50ms" is definitely what i want to know.

Comment: I have one more question. when thread number increment, does the CPU period(tick period) change and how to change?

Comment: Excellent summary. One of the best answers I have seen.

Comment: you said that games usually hold cpu all the time to achieve frame-rate  accurately, why it didn't kick out by tick. if it is kicked, the interval until it get cpu next time is like that it release cpu actively.

Comment: @Panda If all other process has nothing which is very common, kernel won't bother to kick it.